# Ajax file upload error

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I'm using the ajax file upload control in ASP 4.0, it works but when uploading that page on the server (ASP 3.5 framework) it gives me the error "Parameter is not valid". What changes do I have to do in the `web.config` file of 3.5?

Comment: can you post your code on fileupload?.